# Postgres on Heroku: Is it possible to prevent users from logging in to the primary host?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a Postgres 12.3 server running in a primary-follower configuration on Heroku. I added a few credentials to the primary instance, which were replicated to the follower. I would like to prevent users from logging into the primary host.

I understand this is generally possible with `pg_hba.conf`, but I do not believe I have access to this file on Heroku.

Is it possible to achieve this on Heroku?